# $\Phi(\cdot ,x):I_x \rightarrow M$ injective?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I don't understand we the map $\Phi(\cdot ,x):I_x \rightarrow M$ from the excerpt from below of the lecture notes of my professor has to be injectiv.
(Here $M$ denotes the domain of the function on the  RHS of the autonomous ODE, $f$ and $\Phi$ denotes, as usual, the flow of the autonomous ordinary differential equation, defined on the union $\bigcup_{x\in M} I_x \times \{x\}$, where $I_x$ is the maximal open interval of the solution with inital value $x$.)

Here's the excerpt:
[image]

Since $\Phi(\cdot ,x)$ (if I didn't understood it wrong) is just another notation for the solution with inital condition $x$, I would be somewhat astounded, if there weren't injective solutions for autonoums ODEs. (Already the definition of a periodic orbit suggests that  $\Phi(\cdot ,x)$ isn't injective). So does the error lie on my side or is the text faulty ?

Comment: Do you know that $\Phi(t,\Phi(s,x))=\Phi(t+s,x)$? From this you can easily conclude that if $\Phi(\cdot,x)$ is not injective, it must be periodic or stationary.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Yes, I know that relation. But in the way the excerpt puts it, if $\gamma\neq\{x\}$, then $\Phi(\cdot, x)$ is injective. But if $\Phi(\cdot, x)$ is periodic, it fulfills $\gamma\neq\{x\}$ but is *also* not injective. (Or have I made an error in my argumentation ? If so, please provide a (counter)example.)

Comment: No, you are right. I thought the excerpt excluded points with periodic orbit.